# Используются object вместо нужных интерфейсов при добавлении ссылки на службу

Tags: c#, клиент-сервер

Пишу простенькое клиент-серверное приложение. Сервер хранит некоторые данные. Клиент их обрабатывает и отправляет на сервер для других клиентов. Раньше всегда работал со стандартными типами переменных и полей (string и тд). Сейчас возникла нужда использовать свои интерфейсы. Файл IService:

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IServerCallback))]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetString(); //создал "тестовый". Этот отлично работает после добавления ссылки на службу.
    //Так и остаётся возвращаемый тип string

    [OperationContract]
    IUser GetUsers(); //а вот здесь интерфейс заменяется на object
}
```

Сам интерфейс:

```
public interface IUser
{
    Guid Id { get; }

    IUser TryAdd(IUser client);

    void TryRemove(Guid userId);

    IUser? TryFind(Guid userId);
}
```

Раньше всегда использовал стандартные типы (string, int и подобные), поэтому возникла проблема в этом месте.
Архитектура проекта следующая:

-Host (сам сервер). У него есть ссылка на Storage

-Storage (здесь находятся все интерфейсы (в том числе IService), их реализация, перечисления и прочее)

-Client (клиент, который обрабатывает информацию и должен отправлять её на сервер). Он не имеет ссылок на другие проекты

Добавляю вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это работает у меня в голове: Я добавляю ссылку на службу и автоматически создаются нужные ссылки на интерфейсы и тд. Может это нужно как-то задать? Я крайне сильно не хочу добавлять в Client ссылку на весь проект Storage, т.к. это разные проекты, которые не совсем правильно будет "совмещать"

Comment: А если вместо iuser класс подставить user? Я вот просто думаю, при интерфейсе, экземпляр какого типа должен подставиться на клиенте?

Comment: В Service (который реализует IService), есть поле, в котором создаётся экземпляр класса User. Сам метод GetUsers, который реализован в Service просто является аналогом "гетера" из свойства: "public IUser GetUsers() => _users;". Собственно, само поле _users: "private IUser _users => new User();"

Comment: А, я вот сейчас подумал, ведь действительно, какой экземпляр будет подставлен на клиенте, если реализация интерфейса только в проекте Storage. Попробую и дам обратную связь

Comment: Да, теперь всё отлично стало работать. Спасибо. Единственное, я всё же хочу попробовать оставить интерфейсы. Попробую создать промежуточный проект между Storage и Client, в котором будут реализованы конвертеры, чтобы в Client минимальное количество нужной информации уходило

Comment: А смысл ставить интерфейс в апи сервера? Это какой то странный контракт получается. Апи по идее должно быть максимально ясным, а не так что вроде и 5 полей,  а может и 15 полей,  а может и 150 полей. Да и зачем в данных, что передаёшь, писать какие то методы? Контракт работает как - ты вызываешь метод, получаешь в ответ данные. Потому и интерфейс iuser и методы в интерфейсе абсолютно ни к месту.

Comment: Если это WCF, то такое добавление само может генерировать интерфейсы и классы. А ещё можно выносить в отдельную либу типы.

Comment: Да, это именно WCF. Я создал отдельный Shared проект с реализацией интерфейсов, ссылку на который имеет и клиент, и сервер